# Daily distinct Sales using T-SQL for Different Models

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, distinct

This is my input data from a table in db:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwA6v.png)
I want to get below information as output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqKtL.png)

If you observe the output I need to get distinct serial number count for a model from day 1 to till date.
for ex: for day1: count(distinct serialnumber) as sold
day2 : count(distinct serialnumber from day1) as sold
I did this using cumulative sales but because of some serial numbers has multiple sales on different dates, I'm getting a wrong count.
Can anyone please help me with T-SQL query for this request?

Comment: A >>SMALL<< data sample and desired results as TEXT is far more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with two levels of aggregation:

```
select model, sale_date, 
    sum(count(*)) over(partition by model order by sale_date) sale_qty
from (
    select model, serial_number, min(sale_date) sale_date
    from mytable
    group by model, serial_number
) t
group by model, sale_date
order by model, sale_date
```

With this technique, each `serial_number` is counted only once, on its first appearance date.